# How do I return an async Task through another one?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, pass-through

I have two async methods as follows:

```
protected async Task<bool> DoSomething(byte[] data) {
    await System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Do things.");
    Data refinedData = Data.fromByteArray(data);
    return DoSomething(refinedData); // Compiler error!
}

protected async Task<bool> DoSomething(Data data) {
    /* Do way more interesting things with data now that it's our type! */
    return true;
}
```

What I'd like to do is not have to use `await` with my first return statement, but rather, just pass through to the second override of `DoSomething`.  Is there a special method I can call on the return of the second override to defer to it's generated `Task` instance, or a particular language mechanism I can/should use?

Comment: I get a compiler error saying that the first method must return `bool` not `Task<bool>`.

Comment: Remove the async keyword from the first method signature and you should be fine.

Comment: Is that the only solution, or is there a way to get around this without losing the ability to use `await` in these kinds of overrides?

Comment: You're not using await. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @PatrikHägne is right (and my first comment is wrong) - remove `await` and it will be fine. You can `await` anything that returns `Task<T>` - so should not be a problem.

Comment: If you already have `await` (after edit) why not `return await DoSomething(refinedData);` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, because now I can't use `await` from a non-async method.  That results in a compiler error.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The main reason is that at the end of my method, my task is complete.  It becomes more meaningful for it to return the one it's calling next.

Comment: I don't think you can get what you want... also I doubt you would gain much by not specifying second `await` - method is already state machine with on `await` (but if it is a concern please make sure to prototype and carefully measure - my doubt does not mean it is true).

Answer (score 3):

You should either remove the async keyword from the first method signature, OR you should use the await keyword before returning.

`return await DoSomething(refinedData);`

Comment: +1: indeed - no `await` inside => don't mark method `async` and simply return `Task<T>`; with `await` inside - mark `async` and `return await ...`.

Comment: This is the correct approach; it's not possible to 'pass through' as the OP is imagining if the method is async, because the Task representing the `DoSomething(byte[])` async method call is actually returned at the _first_ await in the method, well before it gets to the final return value that should be set as that Task's completion result.

Comment: Warning: removing `async` from the first method's signature will alter its behavior. Specifically, exceptions thrown within it will no longer be encapsulated in a `Task` as callers may expect.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few things about this suggestion that worry me in terms of performance and limitations.